# Why adding NSAssert here causes error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
-(NSArray *) convertArrayOfDictionaryToOneOfItsElement: (NSString *) key
{
    NSArray * result = [self convertEachElementToAnother:^(id element){
        NSDictionary *elementDictionary = (NSDictionary *) element;
        NSString * value= elementDictionary [key];
        //NSAssert(result, @"result must not benil");
        return value;
    }];
    return result;
}
```

This code works fine without NSAssert. However, if things are nil I want to ensure I nkow when it happens.

Well, I put NSAssert

It hangs.

exc_bad_access

Why?

Update: I found the bug. It should be `NSAssert (value, @"result must not benil")`

Well, I still want to know why doing `NSAssert (result,...` cuases problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because inside block you have no result array, this array will assign only after last block execute.